# Assigning a variable to a random selection of names?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble assigning a variable (in this case 'hero') to a random selection of names (Marth, Lucina, etc.) in my project.  Below are a medley of small sections of my code.  (I have to assign this to a variable in order to print out this random text(name) into a canvas.)

PROBLEM: HERO WILL SAY UNDEFINED

```
import random

focus_chance = 3
five_star_chance = 3
four_star_chance = 36
three_star_chance = 58


summon = random.randint(1, 100)

if summon < 4:
    #print('YOU GOT A 5-STAR FOCUS :DD')        
    focus_hero = ['Marth', 'Lucina', 'Robin', 'Tiki']
    hero = random.choice(focus_hero)           

    if summon > 3 and summon < 8:
        #print('YOU GOT A 5-STAR :D')
        five_hero = ['Ogma', 'Cain', 'Corrin', 'Chrom', 'Caeda', 'Ryoma',
                     'Lyn', 'Tiki', 'Tharja', 'Lilina', 'Leo', 'Azura', 'Abel'
                     'Effie'] 
        hero = random.choice(five_hero)

        if summon > 7 and summon < 45:
            #print('You got a 4-star. :)')
            four_hero = ['Hero1','Hero2']
            hero = random.choice(four_hero)

            if summon > 44 and summon < 101:
                #print('You got a 3-star. :(')
                three_hero = ['Hero3', 'Hero4']
                hero = random.choice(three_hero)
print hero
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. Can you give a more concrete example of what exactly you are trying to accomplish? What do you mean exactly by "assigning a variable to a random selection of names". From your code, if `hero` will hold `Marth` as a hero name, what is your expectation of what you want to happen and what is not happening. Furthermore, as you mentioned, this is just a sample of your real code, but just to make sure, you are not really using `null` in your real code right?

Comment: Yes.  This is just a small sample I just simplified.  null isn't in there.  It are a whole lot of other parts just like the if summon < 4:

Comment: it goes all the way to 100

Comment: Can you provide more clarification based on what I asked in my original comment? As is, I don't quite get what you are trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: you want me to post all of my original code?

Comment: No, he's asking you to explain what you're actually trying to do, not dump your entire codebase.

Comment: why not just use summon as the index into focus_hero? hero = focus_hero[summon]

Comment: @JohnnyAppleseed No, please don't show your entire code base. As also clarified by TigerhawkT3, please clarify what you are trying to accomplish exactly. It is really not clear. Please re-read my first comment.

Comment: The object of this code is to make a simulator of a somewhat gambling game.  The 'focus' heros are the special types of heroes you can get.  Out of those focus heroes, you can get one of the four heroes listed in the code for 'focus_hero'

Comment: and seems nothing wrong with your code. what problem did you get?

Comment: This code: `hero = random.choice(focus_hero)` assigns a random `focus_hero` string to the name `hero`. Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: when i print it says hero is not defined when i try to print it

Comment: Then the problem is something else. Please spend some time debugging your own code. If this process itself doesn't lead you to a solution, it'll help you post a better question. As it is, your current question isn't answerable.

Comment: You've got the indentation messed up. All statements starting `if summon` should be at the same level.

Comment: The logic of those `if` statements is a little weird: why are the `summon` ranges overlapping? BTW, rather than writing `summon > 3 and summon < 8` you can write `3 < summon < 8`.

Comment: Wait....all along this problem was an indentation issue? Dude. If you had mentioned in your question you were *actually* getting an error and what error it was, this all would have been avoided.

Comment: sorry i am a high school freshman who has no idea what he is doing

Comment: Next time, please post a [mcve] that illustrates your problem

Comment: @JohnnyAppleseed Don't apologize. Just, next time when someone asks for more info, give the info! :) This is for your benefit :). Good luck with your studies. And, as just mentioned, providing a [mcve] is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that your `if`'s are nested. This means that one `if` can only evaluate if the condition in the `if` above it is true. For example,

```
if summon < 4:
    #Only get here if summon is less than 4

    if summon > 3 and summon < 8:
        #Only get here is summon is less than 4 AND summon is greater than 3 and summon is less than 8
```

The way to fix this would be to indent the `if`'s evenly, thereby making it so that python looks at each one separately:

```
if summon < 4:
    #Only get here if summon is less than 4

if summon > 3 and summon < 8:
    #Only get here when summon is greater than 3 and less than 8
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or nest them and do an if/else statement, with the nesting in the else portion each time. Might stack more, but could potentially be a little faster?